# SpringBoot JPA save in Impala

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, bigdata, impala

I develop a web service whit springboot and I need it save some info in my impala database.

I searching about save in impala and I only find how to use the JDBC.

Someone know if I can use spring boot and spring jpa to save data in impala?

My .yml

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  config:
    name: **
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enable: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:impala://...
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver (I think this is not the correct but i find another)
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC41</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4.1005</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caser.archit.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-caf-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caser.archit.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-caf-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caser.archit.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-caf-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caser.archit.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>security-caf-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Yes. What did you try so far. Do you have any problems  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SimonMartinelli When i try to configure my JPA in application.yml. Spring not recognize my driver-class-name.

Comment: how does your application.yaml and your pom.xml look like?

Comment: Please add this to the question not as a comment. I can'tr ead it

Comment: @SimonMartinelli now, sorry

Answer (score -1):

The driver class name should be

```
driverClassName: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

And use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I try and not found.

The error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the driver dependency

Comment: Same error:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:impala...

Comment: But he says he is going to use impala, not hive